# VMWare Workstation 12 Player - Tiny screen for virtual machine - how can i fix?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am running my VM on Windows 10 through VMWare Workstation 12 Player. I have set everything up and it is operating properly. However the size of the displayed VM screen appears to be fixed at a small size and will not respond to going full screen etc.

[image]

I have attempted to remedy the problem with some research, changing the compatibility options by right clicking on the shortcut and overriding high DPI scaling behaviour.

[image]

This is also the settings for the VM itself...
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
I just changed the global settings in the compatibility options to override the DPI scaling for the `system` rather than the `application`, and this did make the VM actually scale... However it now is too large for the screen, with a scrollable section hiding things off screen?

**Update 2**
After downloading the patch tool as suggested in the answers, I find that I cannot edit the registry since my laptop is locked down by the Admins... No workaround has been found thus far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need download Patch Tool [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7low4e92cj6hd5u/Patch+Tool.zip)
Install VMware Tools for macOS Sierra (Full-Screen Mode)

Comment: That file you linked me to needs a password to unzip?

Comment: Patch Tool Password: www.wikigain.com

Comment: Ah it is this! I have tried this before, but I am using a work laptop so they have locked it down and I get the message: `ERROR: Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator`... Really annoying!
Do you know of any workarounds?